# C - Buffer Overflow Issue

Tags: c, overflow

Here is the source code for the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
% filename: test.c
int main(){
  int local = 0;
  char buff[7];
  printf("Password: ");
  gets(buff);

  if (local)
    printf("Buff: %s, local:%d\n", buff, local);
  return 0;
}
```

I using "gcc test.c -fno-stack-protector -o test" to compile this file, and when I run the file, in order to make the gets overflow, I need to enter at least 13 characters. The way I think is since I only declare 7 bytes to the buff, which means when user enter at least 8 characters, overflow happened. But seems like not this case, why?

Answer (score 1):

The stack layout is implementation dependent.

There is no guarantee that `local` object will be after or before `buff` object or that both will be contiguous.

In your case, what is likely is 5-bytes (1 + 4) of padding were inserted  after `buff` object. Such padding is very common and is usually inserted by the compiler for performance reasons. The size of the padding can vary between compilers, compiler versions, compiler options or even from different source codes.

To have a better idea of the layout just print the addresses of both `buff` and `local` objects:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void *) buff, (void *) local);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gets(buff);
```

There is no default bound check in C. At the best program will crash, usually it will get unallocated memory, so it just works fine. Even sometime you overrun already used memory, and may not realize it till you get into problem.

Comment: I know that line will get buffer overflow, but I don't understand is why when I enter more or equal 13 characters to make that overflow happen, why not 8 characters?

Comment: Its just by chance.. or even compiler keeps buffer after chuck of memory, so if you run same code in different compiler you will get different result. Its unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the items on your stack will be allocated packed tightly together, in fact I'm pretty certain they're not even guaranteed to be put in the same *order.*

If you want to understand *why* it's not failing as you seem to expect, your best bet is to look at the assembler output, with something like `gcc -S`.

For what it's worth, `gcc 4.8.3` under CygWin fails at eight characters as one might expect. It *overflows* at seven characters but, because the overflowing character is the NUL terminator, that still leaves `local` as zero.

Bottom line, undefined behaviour is exactly that. It's *most* annoying feature (to developers) is that it sometimes works, meaning that we sometimes miss it until the code gets out into production. If UB were somehow tied to electrodes connected to the private parts of developers, I guarantee there'd be far fewer bugs :-)

Comment: `7` characters is enough to get an overflow but not to trigger the desired `if (local)`.